# How to stop recursive function modifying it's own variables?

Tags: javascript, sorting, variables, recursion

I'm trying to create a javascript sorting algorithm that uses recursion. It keeps modifying it's own variables. How do i stop this?

An example of this is (psuedocode):

```
function fun():
   a = random 
   fun()
   return a
```

The problem is that running the sort() modifies a from it's original random value to a different one.

I've tried using "this.varname" but that does not seem to make a difference.

My full code is [here](https://pastebin.com/AYhME2BC) and the recursive function is on line 52. The variables that are being overwritten are 'bigger' and 'smaller'.

The code works if you stop it from being recursive (commenting out 68-71) but obviously that means the sort only gets partially completed.If you would like to run the code to test you will need 'p5.js'. I am also sorry for the bad code.

As always, all help is appreciated and I thank you for spending your time helping me (and future googlers).

Bonus Points: Does anyone know what type of sorting function this is?

Comment: Where is `a` declared?  I’m guessing outside the function’s scope.  Make that first line `var a = random` instead and it will be scoped to the function itself.

Comment: Scope, the scope is your problem. define `a` inside `fun` and your problem will go away. I don't know if that's the intention of the code but it will not modify `a` outside of that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm assuming you have a background in python*

In javascript variables "require" one of 3 keywords (let, const, var) before the variable name when declaring them. For example `let a = 10;` in js would be the same as `a = 10` in python. However as you can see, your code does run, so declaring a variable without one of these keywords must work, right? Yes, but not in the way you would expect. `a = 10` in js is the same as `window.a = 10`. So you are actually binding the value 10 to the key "a" on the window object, rather than declaring a functionally scoped variable.

In the example below, `a` inside `foo` is scoped to the function, while `a` inside `bar` is "scoped" to the window object.

```js
function foo() {
  let a = 10
}

function bar() {
  a = 10
}

console.log(window.a)

foo();
console.log(window.a)

bar();
console.log(window.a)
```

Comment: I'm actually from java... I was originally doing a lot of things before declaring variables (java goes OTT in that area) but ended up coming to the conclusion that javascript didn't need them. Thankyou anyway!